# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar goes weird formatting at lower view ratios

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Site: [collecthw.com](http://collecthw.com)

When the NavBar is full screen it takes up 100% of the width of the screen and the search bar is in the NavBar.

On Mobile and when you shrink your browser window, it changes. I can't for the life of me figure out where I should be looking to make it not do this.

Comment: You should be looking in the CSS files.

Comment: be default is the CSS supposed to do this? because I haven't changed anything out of the box for bootstrap and I don't remember it doing it when I integrated it.

Comment: are you adding in the `bootstrap-responsive.css`? If so, there are media queries that will change the styles based on browser width.

Comment: Yes, this happens by default. If you want the items to stay inline at all times, then you need to set a width on the navbar. Otherwise, use the responsive CSS file to make changes to the items.

Comment: I do have responsive loaded and functioning where I'd like it to function. So I just need to go manually edit out the navbar responsive   CSS?

Comment: Yes, you need to modify the media queries found in `bootstrap-responsive.css`...do a find for `.navbar` and make the appropriate mods.

Comment: Thanks fletch, it was this line that was the culprit `@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }` needed to be changed to 0pxs

Comment: Glad you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fletch pointed me to the right direction

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
body {
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

needs changed to

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
body {
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```